# Online Radio as a web service

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, streaming

When starting an online-radio, the problem for me is that I do not want to run a program all the time locally on my computer.
Rather I would like to write a **web service, which automatically and randomly plays a mp3 from an online database**. That way the online radio could be up 24/7 without much trouble.

Is there any framework you know of or is there already an open source web service for this?
More generally, how would you approach this project?

Thanks for any ideas and suggestions!
Dietmar

Comment: revise the tags please.. why `query` or `aws`?

Comment: Another consideration, is it really good to randomly select songs? I would argue that your customers only listen to certain songs.In addition, the distribution is important, do you want to hear the same song 3 times in a week while another one is played once every 4 years? Why would you play a recent song at 3 am when the majority is not listening...  i would spend a thought to the business side first

Comment: @OliverStutz yes, that is true - but I am looking for a general implementation, I think the details can be adjusted later.